# Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service while enabling copy-paste

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox, copy-paste

I try to enable copy-paste functionality in the Oracle Virtual Box. In order to accomplish this, I run:

```
sudo /usr/bin/VBoxClient --clipboard
```

and I get

```
Failed to connect to the VirtualBox kernel service
```

What does this mean and how can I solve it? I tried to launch the Virtual Box with sudo, it did not work.
I mention that I have `virtualbox-guest-utils` and `virtualbox-guest-x11` installed.
Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you ran Insert Guest Additions CD Image from the VirtualBox menu and ran the disk in your VM.

I had a similar issue where my **Bidirectional Clipboard** was working and then stopped after an update. I was getting the error message displayed: **vboxclient the virtualbox kernel service is not running**. Reinserting the Insert Guest Additions CD Image and reinstalling the services **FIXED** my issue.

I am using VirtualBox ver. 5.0.20. with Fedora 23 VM.

Answer (score 3):

I am using VirtualBox 5.0.6 and I got the same error after I updated my guest virtual machine. This solved it for me.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
```

Then I used `sudo /usr/bin/VBoxClient --clipboard` to enable clipboard and it worked.

If you are using VirtualBox pre 5.x, use this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup
```

Check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/678175/360987) for the [VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 - vboxclient the virtualbox kernel service is not running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642991/virtualbox-ubuntu-14-04-vboxclient-the-virtualbox-kernel-service-is-not-runnin) question.

Comment: I've been having this same issue with an Ubuntu guest with a Mac OSX host. I did an apt-get update and apt-get dist-upgrade and now whenever I try to log in I get that cannot connect to kernel error. Being a Mac host, I have no /etc/init.d/vboxadd. I did a find / -iname vbox* and didn't see anything that looked like vboxadd OR vboxdrv...

Answer (score 0):

How I got it working for me:

My setup:

- VirtualBox 6.0.4
- Host machine - Ubuntu 18.04
- Guest machine in virtualbox - Kali 2019.1 kernel version 4.19.0

Install needed packages with apt on GUEST machine

```
apt-get install build-essential virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11 virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

After this, run:

```
VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Also, make sure that you have enabled Shared Clipboard from Settings>General>Advanced on the HOST machine.

Now it should be working :)